# DIV not showing with specified background color

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code with CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        div.scroll
        {
            background-color:#00FFFF;
            position:absolute;
            top:0%;
            left:0%;
            width:10%;
            height:100%;
        }

        div.hidden 
        {
            background-color:#00FF00;
            position:absolute;
            top:0%;
            left:50%;
            width:20%;
            height:100%;
        }

        div.menu
        {
            position:absolute;
            top:70%;
            left:20%;
            width:80%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p>The overflow property specifies what to do if the content of an element exceeds the size of the element's box.</p>

    <div class="menu">
        <div class="scroll">Scroll: You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.</div>
        <div class="hidden">Hidden: You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

As you can see I want two of the divisions to have color - they don't and I can't figure out why.  The file has an html extension and I have used both IE7 and FF 3.0.3 to test.

What perplexes me the most is that it is almost a verbatim copy of an example from W3C schools that does show color!  Link to example: [W3C example](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow).

Comment: It is not surprising that something you found on W3Schools did not work as you hoped. See http://w3fools.com

Comment: Had no idea - made me laugh though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `height:100%;` . It means that the element use all the height of its parent, in this case the `<div class="menu">`, which is 0px because all its content is positioned with `absolute`.

You can either remove it if you want each `div` of have the size of its text, or set a height in pixel if you want to apply the same height to the both divs.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You can see the effect of `height:100%` if you additionally set `overflow:hidden`, demonstrating that the element has zero height, so that all content overflows and is thus shown (if it is shown) outside the element’s area.

Comment: I selected this answer because it more fully explained what was going on which allowed me to make a different change to achieve my desired results.  Specifically I did not remove the height attribute from scroll or hidden but added a height:30% to the menu attribute.  Once the menu div had height everything behaved the way I wanted.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `height: 100%;` from your `div.scroll` and `div.hidden` CSS classes.